# CacheApi doesn't mind the EhCache configuration for timeToIdle

Tags: java, playframework, ehcache, playframework-2.5

I'm setting cache in play framework 2.5.6 and strugglling with timeToIdle property.

My configuration follows the one provided in official [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCache)

conf/ehcache.xml:

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false"
         monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" />
    <cache name="userSession"
           maxEntriesLocalHeap="100000"
           maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000"
           eternal="false"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"

           timeToIdleSeconds="3"

           transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

conf/application.conf:

```
play.cache {
    bindCaches = ["userSession"]
    createBoundCaches = false
}
```

In code I'm obtaining cache by injection with `@Inject @NamedCache("userSession")`.

Cache is injected and possible to use, but from what I observe, the timeToIdleInSeconds is not used.

My configuration is for sure resolved, cause in logs I can find:

```
2016-10-21 11:46:46,086 DEBUG n.s.e.config.ConfigurationFactory  ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1  [] - Configuring ehcache from URL: file:/src/LR/lr-facade/target/scala-2.11/classes/ehcache.xml
```

I've tried to debug codes and found that in play implementation of EhCache there is:

`play-cache_2.11-2.5.6-sources.jar!/play/api/cache/Cache.scala`:

```
  def set(key: String, value: Any, expiration: Duration) = {
    val element = new Element(key, value)
    expiration match {
      case infinite: Duration.Infinite => element.setEternal(true)
      case finite: FiniteDuration =>
        val seconds = finite.toSeconds
        if (seconds <= 0) {
          element.setTimeToLive(1)
        } else if (seconds > Int.MaxValue) {
          element.setTimeToLive(Int.MaxValue)
        } else {
          element.setTimeToLive(seconds.toInt)
        }
    }
    cache.put(element)
  }
```

As you can see, if I don't provide ttl `eternal` is set to true. From what I've read in EhCache [docs](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/configuration/data-life.html) if eternal is set, for whole cache, ttl and tti doesn't matter any more. From codes I see that if eternal is set for `Element`, `tti` and `ttl` are set to `0`:

`ehcache-core-2.6.11-sources.jar!/net/sf/ehcache/Element.java`:

```
public void setEternal(final boolean eternal) {
    if (eternal) {
        this.cacheDefaultLifespan = false;
        this.timeToIdle = 0;
        this.timeToLive = 0;
    } else if (isEternal()) {
        this.cacheDefaultLifespan = false;
        this.timeToIdle = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        this.timeToLive = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
}
```

Anyone had the same problem? Anyone found solution for it?

Of course I know I could resolve it by setting a timestamp in cache and checking if it should expire by myslef.

[update]

forget that i've changed during testing the conf and removed for a moment eternal property from . But all the tests I've made before proven that either this is set or not, eternal property is always true (as it comes from the playCache codes).

Answer (score 0):

I can only confirm this is the behaviour of the `Cache` abstraction in Play using `Ehcache`.

Unless you explicitly define an expiration `Duration` when putting entries into the `Cache`, mappings are configured to be *eternal* at the mapping level. This means that any `Cache` level expiration configuration is effectively ignored because mappings will always specify a per-mapping setting.

Note also that Play only offers support for *time-to-live* / *TTL*, not *time-to-idle* / *TTI* which I believe is a good thing because *TTI* is really closer to a capacity control than a freshness one.